# AWS Marketplace Catalog API - possible values ProductState in result of DescribeEntity action for AmiProduct / ContainerProduct

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-marketplace, amazon-marketplace

I need to parse programmatically response of [DescribeEntity action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace-catalog/latest/api-reference/API_DescribeEntity.html) of AWS Marketplace Catalog API for AmiProduct / ContainerProduct.

Specification is not explaining details of schema per type of entity - details (including ProductState possible values) which are specific to each entity type are contained in Details property in response, which is [stringified JSON object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace-catalog/latest/api-reference/API_DescribeEntity.html#API_DescribeEntity_ResponseSyntax).

From my test data I was able to extract current state value ("Active").

Does anybody know what are the other possible values of ProductState property?